# Accessing Locked phone with swipe pattern to initialize ADB debugging FROM pc, the screen is black and non responsive

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

screen got broken on my A50 and although my pc can see an MTP device, i need to allow debugging. but i cant cause i cant see anything . is there a way to initialize this from PC and ADB??

please help,
thank you,
nick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The simple answer is no (if it would work this would be a major security vulnerability). On an unrooted phone you can enable adb only by entering the debugging menu and activate it and then authorize your computer as trusted.